Issue with react useState
I do not really know if I am configuring this wrongly or not.
const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState<string>('');

The declaration above is supposed to be set from the button, see below
<ul>
    <li className="relative flex items-center" ref={refMenu}>
    {/* <button type="button"
        onClick={(e) => { setOpenMenu(menus.nav); console.log(e.target) }}>
        <div className="text-site-color">
            <Bars3Icon className="h-9 w-9" />
        </div>
    </button> */}

    <button type="button" onClick={() => handleOpenMenu(menus.nav)}>
        <div className="text-site-color">
        <Bars3Icon className="h-9 w-9" />
        </div>
    </button>

    {openMenu == menus.nav && (
        <ul
        className="absolute z-20 borde 
            border-gray-100 shadow bg-white w-56 p-0 rounded top-[54px] 
            overflow-hidden"
        >
        {/* <li className="mb-1 bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 px-2 py-1">
        </li> */}
        <li className="mb-1 bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 px-2 py-1 flex items-center">
            <ShoppingBagIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
            <Link className="ml-3" to="/products">
            All products
            </Link>
        </li>
        </ul>
    )}
    </li>
</ul>
                          

Now, the issue is that the variable, openMenu, seems to be set briefly and immediately unset.
N/B: I am using react-detect-click-outside package to unset if the
Edited
function handleOpenMenu(action: string){
    setOpenMenu(action) 
    console.log(action)
    console.log(openMenu) // this erroneously returned <empty string>
}


What is the definition of handleOpenMenu?
